# A problem about elliptic differential equations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Suppose $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the weak solution of the following equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\left(a^{ij}(x)u_i\right)_j +b^iu_i=\sin u(x),x\in \Omega\\
u(x)=0,x\in \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $\partial \Omega\in C^{\infty},a^{ij}=a^{ij}\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ is uniformly elliptic ,$b^i\in  C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$.Show that
$$
u\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})
$$

I want to use $H^k$-regularity theorey to prove it, so I need to prove  if $u\in H^{m+1}(\Omega)$ then $\sin u(x)\in H^{m}(\Omega)$.However, what I can deal with is the cases when $m=1$.